# Problems with installing Xcode on Mac 10.10.5 ( Locations - setting)

Tags: macos, terminal, xcode

I have followed the steps for the installation from www.instalrails.com . 
After installing Xcode they say to check the Preferences -> Location 
and have ensure you have the command line tools - Xcode 5.0.2 ( 5A3005 )
http://installrails.com/steps/install_xcode

But in my command line tools *Xcode 7.1.1 (7B1005)* appears and I cannot modify it.

I left it as it is and then tried to write this simple command in Terminal and it does not work :

```
$ jot - 1 25
```

It says command not found.

Can you please give some directions.

Answer (score 1):

The linked picture in the install guide

[image]

is simply wrong. After installing the latest Xcode 7.1.1 the command line tools version is indeed Xcode 7.1.1 (7B1005).

*jot* is an executable (it prints sequential or random data) residing in /usr/bin. The purpose of executing `jot - 1 25` is to ensure that the $PATH variable is set properly in your environment. If it can't be executed your $PATH variable probably doesn't include /usr/bin.

To get your current $PATH variable enter `echo $PATH`. The default $PATH in Yosemite looks like this:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

To restore the proper $PATH variable use one of the various answers here at [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%24PATH%20Yosemite).

Comment: Thank you so much!. P.s I have tried         jot - 1 25   whiteout the $ and it works. also echo $PATH works.

Comment: Last login: Wed Nov 11 00:28:47 on ttys000
MacBook-Air-ul-lui-Eduard:~ prime_user$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
MacBook-Air-ul-lui-Eduard:~ prime_user$ q
-bash: q: command not found
MacBook-Air-ul-lui-Eduard:~ prime_user$ jot 1 125
125
MacBook-Air-ul-lui-Eduard:~ prime_user$ $ jot - 1 25
-bash: $: command not found
MacBook-Air-ul-lui-Eduard:~ prime_user$  jot - 1 25
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25

Comment: @EduardPetru Ok it was simple mistake

Comment: Thank you, I am at the very beginning, a lot learn but there is passion :-D